# Проблема редактирования статей Confluence в Firefox

Tags: firefox, confluence

Последнее время (1-2 месяца) при редактировании стилей (например: смена цвета текста, смена отступа) в статье Confluence экран автоматически перескакивает в начало (вверх) страницы. В Google Chrome проблемы нет.
У кого-нибудь были подобные проблемы? Как решить не меняя браузер?

Comment: Такая же проблема, в FIREFOX не возможно работать в Confluence. Как в поддержку FIREFOX написать?

Comment: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org

Comment: Судя по ошибке в консоле, проблема связана с асинхронными панорамированием, которое нестабильно работает с реализованным в Confluence эффектом позиционирования связанного с прокруткой. Сам текст ошибки: "Похоже, что этот сайт использует эффект позиционирования связанный с прокруткой. Это может не очень хорошо работать с асинхронным панорамированием; см. https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Mozilla/Performance/ScrollLinkedEffects чтобы получить более подробную информацию и присоединиться к обсуждению связанных с этим инструментов и возможностей!".

Comment: Решением вижу только устанавливать раннюю версию браузера, например 79 - в ней работает нормально.